# Flask API to create a Jira ticket

Tags: python, flask, jira, datadog

I am working on a Flask API, that creates a new user in Datadog and creates a Jira ticket, but while I run this, while a new user is created in Datadog, it does not create a Jira ticket for the same. I am not sure what is going wrong, I do not get any error while running the API. My guess is the URL I am providing could be wrong but following the Jira documentation creates so many combinations, I am not sure if that is right.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import requests
import os

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='./scenes/datadog', static_url_path='/scenes/datadog')
CORS(app)
@app.route('/datadog/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/datadog/<path:path>')
def serve_static(path):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
load_dotenv()
@app.route('/create_user', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    datadog_api_key = "11"
    datadog_app_key = "11"
    jira_api_key = '1-1-1-1-1=1'
    jira_url = 'https://pkidev.atlassian.net'

    datadog_headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'DD-API-KEY': datadog_api_key,
        'DD-APPLICATION-KEY': datadog_app_key
    }
    name = request.form.get('name')
    email = request.form.get('email')
    role = request.form.get('role')
    # create user in datadog
    datadog_data = {
        "handle": email,
        "name": name,
        "role": role
    }
    datadog_url = "https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v1/users"
    datadog_response = requests.post(datadog_url, headers=datadog_headers, verify=False, json=datadog_data)
    if datadog_response.status_code != 200:
        return "User creation failed. Please check your input and try again."
    print("User created in Datadog")

    # create jira ticket
    jira_headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jira_api_key
    }
    jira_data = {
        "fields": {
            "project": {
                "key": "SP"
            },
            "summary": "New user created in Datadog: " + name,
            "description": "A new user has been created in Datadog:\n\nName: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email + "\nRole: " + role,
            "issuetype": {
                "name": "DevOps Task"
            },
            "status": {
                "statusCategory": {
                    "key": "new"
                }
            },
            "reporter": {
                "name": "Bhavya Mamidi"
            },
            "assignee": {
                "name": "Bhavya Mamidi"
            }
        }
    }
    jira_base_url = jira_url + "/rest/api/3/issue"
    jira_response = requests.post(jira_base_url, headers=jira_headers, json=jira_data, verify=False)
    print("Jira API response status:", jira_response.status_code)
    print("Jira API response reason:", jira_response.reason)
    print("Jira API response content:", jira_response.content)
    if jira_response.status_code != 201:
        return "Jira ticket creation failed. Please check your input and try again."
    print("Jira API response:", jira_response.content)

    return "User created successfully and Jira ticket created!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```